# Is there any point to string(string(.)) in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am dealing with some auto-generated XSLT code.

It contains the following:

```
string(string(.))
number(string(.))
string(number(string(.)))
```

Is there any point to these? Or are they reducible to

```
string(.)
number(.)
string(.)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Martin says.

There are edge cases in XPath 2.0 where number(string(.)) is not exactly the same as number(.), for example if the context item is an instance of xs:gYear then number(.) will fail but number(string(.)) will succeed; contrariwise, if the context item is a boolean, number(.) will convert true to 1 and false to 0, while number(string(.)) converts both to NaN. But it's very unlikely that these edge cases are important to your application.

Comment: Is number(string(.) reducible to number(.) ?

Comment: I think I included that case above.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one I am pretty sure it can be reduced to `string(.)`. For the third one I don't think you can reduce it to `string(.)` as for instance for the context node having a character as its string content (e.g. `<foo>a</foo>`) doing `number(string(.))` gives you the special number value "not a number" and if you do `string()` on that again you get (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) the string "NaN". I am not sure about the second being reducible, maybe you can check the details of edge cases with the links I provided.

Comment: Is number(string(.) reducible to number(.) ?